# MySQL Generate a list of names that appear in more than one column, grouped alphabetically

Tags: mysql, join, distinct, union, temporary

I need to create a digest of records which are grouped by names in a table.  The problem is, my table has two columns for names and the same names can be in either column.  The digest should list all names and the records in which they exist, regardless of which column.

I can see doing this by first generating a unique list of names from both columns, then scanning through the result to see if the names appear in either column.  I want to know if MySQL can do this in one query.

Example, here's my table:

```
Id ColumnA Column B
 1   Bill    NULL
 2   NULL    Dennis
 3   Adam    Carl
 4   NULL    Adam
 5   Adam    Bill
 6   Dennis  NULL
 7   Frank   Bill
```

The result of the query (NULL sorts to the top)

```
NULL    4  NULL    Adam
NULL    1  Bill    NULL
NULL    2  NULL    Dennis
NULL    6  Dennis  NULL
Adam    5  Adam    Bill
Adam    7  Adam    Carl
Bill    1  Bill    NULL
Bill    5  Adam    Bill
Bill    6  Frank   Bill
Carl    3  Adam    Carl
Dennis  2  NULL    Dennis
Dennis  6  Dennis  NULL
Frank   7  Frank   Bill
```

It would be nice if I could eliminate the NULL entries at the top of the list.  I only put them there because everything I'm trying so far has them at the top.  I'd rather the result looks like this:

```
Adam    5  Adam    Bill
Adam    7  Adam    Carl
Bill    1  Bill    NULL
Bill    5  Adam    Bill
Bill    6  Frank   Bill
Carl    3  Adam    Carl
Dennis  2  NULL    Dennis
Dennis  6  Dennis  NULL
Frank   7  Frank   Bill
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a union of `ID, ColumnA` with `ID, ColumnB`, then summarize and order the result.

Like so http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eeec6/5/0:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id ORDER BY id) AS ids
  FROM (
        SELECT id, a AS name
          FROM names
         UNION 
        SELECT id, b AS name
          FROM names
        ) AS t
 WHERE name IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY name
 ORDER BY name
```

This will give you one row per name, with a list of IDs (row numbers) containing that name.

Or you can simply display the name, id columns one at a time(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eeec6/6/0):

```
SELECT name, id
  FROM (
        SELECT id, a AS name
          FROM names
         UNION 
        SELECT id, b AS name
          FROM names
        ) AS t
 WHERE name IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY name, id
```

Finally, if you want to show the whole row with each name, you can do this (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eeec6/8/0):

```
SELECT name, n.id, n.a, n.b
  FROM (
        SELECT id, a AS name
          FROM names
         UNION 
        SELECT id, b AS name
          FROM names
        ) AS t
  JOIN names AS n ON t.id = n.id
 WHERE name IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY name, n.id
```

Comment: PERFECT!  Thanks for all the links and step by step.  I understand it now.  And it's very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
SELECT s.ColumnA AS digest_name
     , s.ID
     , s.ColumnA
     , s.ColumnB
  FROM mydata s
 WHERE s.ColumnA IS NOT NULL

 UNION ALL

SELECT t.ColumnB
     , t.ID
     , t.ColumnA
     , t.ColumnB
  FROM mydata t
 WHERE t.ColumnB IS NOT NULL

 ORDER BY 1, 3, 4
```

One query gets all the rows where ColumnA is not null, the second query gets the rows where Column B is not null. (This effectively omits rows where the digest name would have been NULL.)

The `UNION ALL` set operator combines the two sets of rows into a single set. (NOTE: We prefer the more efficient `UNION ALL` operator over the `UNION` operator, because it doesn't perform the extra work of identifying and removing duplicate rows, when that operation isn't required.)

The `ORDER BY` specifies that the rows are to be ordered by the digest name first, then by the names in `ColumnA` and `ColumnB`.

---

This produces ten rows of output, and includes row:

```
digest   Id ColumnA  ColumnB
-------- -- -------- --------
Adam      4 NULL     Adam
```

It's not clear why this row is omitted from the resultset specified in the question. (That resultset in the question shows only nine rows.)

So, I'm not sure if I'm missing something about the requirement. It's entirely possible I've not understood the specification.